# What do the numbers #/# after a name listed in a Perforce depot mean (in P4V)?

Tags: perforce

When looking at perforce depot in P4V, an xml file would be read `some_file.xml #3/3 <text>`.  What does this `#3/3` mean?

I have files that are `#0/1`, and do not end up in my workspace when I sync.  Scrolling over it gives "not synced in your workspace".  Are these related?

Answer (score 9):

The number to the left of the slash is the revision of that file that you have in your workspace, the number to the right of the slash is the number of revisions of that file that exist on the Perforce server.  If you see `some_file.xml #n/n <text>` you have the latest revision of that file (the numbers match).

[image]

If you see a zero on the left side of the slash (e.g., `some_file.xml #0/n <text>`), that means the file exists in version control, but it does not exist in your workspace.

[image]

If the number on the left is anything between 0 and n, you have some previous revision of the file.  P4V will indicate this with a yellow triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`#3/3` means you have version 3 and the maximum version available is 3

`#0/1` means you have code that is not committed to your workspace (I don't think the 1 has any significance other than adding this version will produce version 1).

Looking at the documentation, I think more generally the meaning is "yours/theirs".  In this case, I would see `#0/1` as meaning you don't have a version locally, but there is a version available.  Therefore if you sync, you'll get the version locally and hence has `#1/1`.

Comment: With respect to the #0/1, it is clearly checked in.  When I right click and hit "Get Revision", it shows up in my workspace, but when I force sync that workspace, it disappears again?

Comment: Do you mean it is in your change-list, but not committed?

Comment: Nope.  I have no change lists to commit.  I see it in the depot.  I committed these files as adds yesterday, and they don't seem to be mapping to the workspace unless I manually sync them.

Comment: More potential information, in my workspace I have a folder //workspace/folder/... which has two separate depot folders mapped onto it.  I know these files and their file names are unique, so that is not the issue, but maybe this changes things

Comment: With respect to your edit, it does not appear to be that "if you sync you'll get the version locally".  If I manually right click them and sync, I get the version locally.  However, if I force sync on my workspace, I lose the files!  This is why I am confused.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's something to do with two workspaces pointed to the same directory.  I can only get `#0/1` to show on the depot files I don't have synced to the workspace.  Sorry I can't be more help!